# Проблема с метками на главной странице, если не авторизован на сайте

Tags: дефект, метки

Если зайти на сайт без логина (проще всего в приватном режиме браузера), то на [главной странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) есть небольшой блок с метками:

> [image]

Нажатие на любую из них приводит к необъяснимому результату, хотя должны быть отображены вопросы с этой меткой.

На первый взгляд кажется, что просто происходит обновление страницы с учётом кэширования, но без фактической фильтрации по метке.

На [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), например, фильтрация работает как надо.

Comment: По клику происходит переход по ссылке вида `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tags=c%2b%2b`, а не `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b`, как у рабочих меток справа.